# What is the rank of a square bracket initialized array in Fortran 2008?

Tags: arrays, constructor, fortran, fortran2008

I want to understand if the following Fortran code complies with the Fortran 2008 standard.

```
module m
  implicit none

  type t
     integer, allocatable, dimension(:) :: r
  end type t

contains

  function tt(a,b)
    implicit none
    type(t), allocatable, dimension(:) :: tt
    type(t), intent(in), dimension(:) :: a,b
    allocate(tt, source = [a,b])     ! Is this square bracket correct ?
    return
  end function tt

  function ts(arg)
    implicit none
    type(t), allocatable, dimension(:) :: ts
    integer, intent(in) :: arg(:)
    allocate(ts(1))
    allocate(ts(1)%r, source = arg)
    return
  end function ts
end module m

program p
  use m
  implicit none
  type(t), dimension(2) :: c
  c=tt(ts([99,199,1999]),ts([42,142]))
  if (any (c(1)%r .ne. [99,199,1999])) STOP 1
  if (any (c(2)%r .ne. [42,142])) STOP 2
end program p
```

This above code works fine with `gfortran-9.4.0` and generates the expected output.
Since I am a beginner in Fortran, I got confused by a square bracket expression (marked in the code).

Inside the function `tt`, both `a` and `b` are `t` type arrays. In this example, both of them only have array size of 1.

What is `[a,b]`?
I think it is an array initialized with square brackets, but each of its element is a `t` type array. (Not a `t` type scalar)

What is `[a,b]`'s **rank**? Does it match the return value `tt` which is also a `t` type allocatable array?

From Fortran 2008 standard

> Each allocate-object shall be type compatible (4.3.1.3) with
> source-expr . If SOURCE= appears, source-expr shall be a scalar or
> have the same rank as each allocate-object.

Comment: If `a` and `b` are rank 1, then `[a,b]` is rank 1.  You can test this with the `rank` intrinsic subprogram.

Comment: And `tt` is also declared with rank 1, all is fine.

Comment: In terms of semantic, It seems `[a, b]` could concatenate the their orginal value to form a longer array which each of its element is a type of `t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[a,b]` here is an *array constructor*.<sup>1</sup>

An array constructor creates a rank-1 array.  This is the case:

- in every revision of the Fortran standard (F90+)
- whether the array constructor uses `(/ ... /)` or `[ ... ]`
- whatever the use of the array constructor as an expression
- whatever the type of the constructed array and its sequence values

Coming to the specifics of the question:

> What is `[a,b]` ? I think it is a array initialized with square brackets, but each of its element is a `t` type array. (Not a `t` type scalar)

An array constructor acts with sequences. If an array expression (including a whole array designator) appears inside the constructor, the constructor uses the elements of the array in element order. This means that

```
allocate(tt, source = [a,b])
```

is taken to be

```
allocate(tt, source = [a(1), a(2), ..., b(1), b(2), ...])
```

as a rank-1 array, not an array of arrays or a higher rank array.

> What is `[a,b]`'s rank ? Is it match the return value `tt` which is also a `t` type allocatable array ?

As already noted, it's a rank-1 array, (with those values of `a` and `b` in element orders).

The value of an expression for a `source=` specifier in the allocation is, as nearly everywhere else, independent of the use it's put to. That, is it must be compatible with the type of `tt` but it isn't constructed to be. The expression is created then, if necessary, converted to the type of `tt`.

Consider the case with reals:

```
double precision x(5)
x = [1., 2., 3., 4., 5.2]
end
```

The array constructor is a real expression, not a double precision expression. Once constructed, it's converted to a double precision value for the assignment.

Finally, note that constructed arrays are themselves never allocatable.

---

<sup>1</sup> Most often something which looks like `[a,b]` is an array constructor. However, for completeness, in some circumstances it can be a (coarray) image selector. There can never be ambiguity as to which case we have.

Answer (score 1):

In Fortran 2008, array constructors are defined in the 4.8 chapter of the standard.

The very first sentence in point 1 says

> An array constructor constructs **a rank-one array** value from a sequence
> of ...

Hence, all arrays constructed using the array constructor are of rank 1. Higher ranks can be created from them using `reshape()`.